# Receiving mails fails (milter service connection refusal)

Tags: email, postfix, plesk

I'm currently operating a server, on which runs a mailserver. The mailserver was configured by plesk and it worked fine until those messages appeared in my maillog:

```
/var/log/maillog

postfix/smtpd[17798]: connect from mail-ig0-f194.google.com[209.85.213.194]
postfix/smtpd[17798]: warning: connect to Milter service inet:127.0.0.1:12768: Connection refused
postfix/smtpd[17798]: NOQUEUE: milter-reject: CONNECT from mail-ig0-f194.google.com[209.85.213.194]: 451 4.7.1 Service unavailable - try again later; proto=SMTP
postfix/smtpd[17798]: NOQUEUE: milter-reject: EHLO from mail-ig0-f194.google.com[209.85.213.194]: 451 4.7.1 Service unavailable - try again later; proto=SMTP helo=<mail-ig0-f194.google.com>
postfix/smtpd[17798]: lost connection after STARTTLS from mail-ig0-f194.google.com[209.85.213.194]
postfix/smtpd[17798]: disconnect from mail-ig0-f194.google.com[209.85.213.194]
```

Those messages were written when I tried to send a mail (using gmail) to this mailserver. So apparently they can not be delivered because of `Milter service` which does a connection refusal. Because of that I looked up many ressources in the internet regarding this error, but none of the suggested fixes worked.

As one answer mentios to fix the **postfix setting** for Milter, here is an excerpt of the current setting:

```
grep "milter" /etc/postfix/main.cf
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:12768
non_smtpd_milters =
```

Another answer suggests that the **free space** for partition /var/ might not be enough. But well, it looks good though: 153 GB free space on /var/.

Do you have any suggestion what can be the cause of this error?

Additional system info:

- Ubuntu 14
- Plesk 12
- Postfix 2

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem with Debian Jessie and Plesk 12.5.30.
Solution for me was to start the "pc-remote" service:

```
service pc-remote start
```

Answer (score 0):

Start the milter service **OR** remove `inet:127.0.0.1:12768` from `smtpd_milters` (postfix will not attempt to use it).

Less recomended option is to make postfix ignore milter errors by setting `milter_default_action = accept`.

http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html

Comment: I would preferr the first option, but can not find a source on how to start the milter service. I already tried `service postfix restart` but the problem still exists.

Comment: Do you know which particular milter is not started? [There are many different milters]

Comment: No, the only thing I know - is the error message that occurs in the maillog. How to find out what milters can run? Or other suggestions?

Comment: The following command may give you a hint about installed milter packages: `dpkg -l '*milter*` (It works on Debian)

Comment: `sw-libmilter` is installed. Now I know the package. Excuse me for the lack of knowledge, but how do I start milter?